# PHP 7.2.1 count(null)

Tags: php, warnings

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    count(null);
    echo "Hello World";
    count(null);
```

In PHP 7.2.1 this will cause a PHP warning.

```
PHP Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.php on line 3
PHP Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.php on line 5
```

The "Hello World" doesn't get output. This PHP warning is different from a normal PHP warning. A normal PHP warning usually looks like

**Warning:** Some PHP warning in X on line X

I thought a warning wouldn't prevent the output of data? It seems to in my case.

Running PHP 7.2.1 on IIS 8 - Windows Server 2012 R2

[PHP - Count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://3v4l.org/bZCgq

Comment: Seems so, i'll investigate further on the server, though I've got two separate servers producing the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier I was playing about with the config and had enabled the setting

```
fastcgi.logging=1;
```

Disabling it has restored normal errors.